# SharePoint Online App Development - ProfilePropertyImage

Tags: sharepoint-online

Development for SharePoint Online 2013.
I am trying to create an app - Im using the Profile Property Image control SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage.

I have followed the below steps
1. Registered the namespace

< % @  Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %

2. Added the controles

< SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage PropertyName="PictureUrl" ResizeToFit="100" RenderWrapTable="True" ShowPlaceholder="true" id="PictureUrlImage" runat="server"/ >

I have tried development in NAPA as well as the Visual studio

Kindly find the 2 errors below I've uploaded

Appreciate if u could help me with a solution for the same :)

[image]>
[image]